# linking navigation drawer menu with the activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

i have created an app in which there is a tab layout with 3 tabs along with a navigation drawer.Now i want to link activity with my navigation menu.can anybody tell me how to do that.i have searched on every sites but doesn't find any solution.there is ways to link with the fragment but no one tells about how to link it with the activity.

so anybody having any idea about linking the activity with the navigation drawer menu

Comment: What do you mean by "link"? Change the content of the navigation drawer based on the selected tab or change the content/tabs/activity when a navigation entry is pressed?

Comment: Why don't you share your code and we'll figure out the rest?